# How to determine if the computer has a wifi adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, wifi, wmi

Which way can I decide the computer has a wifi adapter?
When I test my code it works, but I am uncertain, will it always work?

```
private bool hasWifi()
{
    try
    {
        WlanClient wlanclient = new WlanClient();
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception except)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx) to look at what is installed.

```
private bool hasWifi()
{
    return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Any(nic => nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211);
}
```